# Make images all same size

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to make circular images on a page but I wanted them to be the same size and try to keep the aspect ratio. **Since they are different sizes, it looks horrible.** I wanted to make them look like the yellow guy image.

[image: MY CURRENT LAYOUT]

```css
.person {
  border: 10px solid transparent;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
  width: auto;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  opacity: 0.7;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.person:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container text-center">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <p><strong>Counter-Strike</strong></p>
      <br />
      <a href="">
        <img class="person" src="http://i.imgur.com/Zckhfao.jpg" />
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <p><strong>Rainbow 6: Siege</strong></p>
      <br />
      <img class="img-circle person" src="http://i.imgur.com/Dho2UVH.png" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <p><strong>FIFA</strong></p>
      <br />
      <img class="person" src="http://i.imgur.com/Dho2UVH.png" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <p><strong>League of Legends</strong></p>
      <br />
      <img class="person" src="http://i.imgur.com/Dho2UVH.png" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <p><strong>Racing</strong></p>
      <br />
      <img class="person" src="http://i.imgur.com/Dho2UVH.png" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <p><strong>Battlefield</strong></p>
      <br />
      <img class="person" src="http://i.imgur.com/bFg40Dj.jpg" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you create a demo with placeholder images? Thanks

Comment: You appear to be combining `img` tags with css properties for `background-image`. You may find it easier to get the effect you want by replacing the `img` tags with a div and sticking with `background-image`

Comment: the images are all missing.... I couldn't see any image. You could use image responsive. Since you have given a static size style(200px), its maybe image alignment issue.

Comment: use `img-responsive` class along with `img-circle` inside image tag like this `<img class="img-circle img-responsive" src="path" alt="">`

Answer (score 0):

you might need to apply `height:auto and max-width: 100%;` to you `img`

```css
.person {
  border: 10px solid transparent;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
  width: auto;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  opacity: 0.7;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.person:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

.myrow img{
 height:auto;
 max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container text-center">
  <div class="row myrow">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <p><strong>Counter-Strike</strong></p><br />
      <a href=@Url.Action( "PC", "Gaming")>
        <img class="person" src="https://baconmockup.com/300/200/" />
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <p><strong>Rainbow 6: Siege</strong></p><br />
      <img class="img-circle person" src="https://baconmockup.com/300/200/" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <p><strong>FIFA</strong></p><br />
      <img class="person" src="https://baconmockup.com/300/200/" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <p><strong>League of Legends</strong></p><br />
      <img class="person" src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/zrwRmR6MKeg/maxresdefault.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <p><strong>Racing</strong></p><br />
      <img class="person" src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/zrwRmR6MKeg/maxresdefault.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <p><strong>Battlefield</strong></p><br />
      <img class="person" src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/zrwRmR6MKeg/maxresdefault.jpg" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep your image in an `img` tag, you can use the [`object-fit`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit) property to force the image to adapt to its container. You might also need a polyfill for browser support, I suggest the [lazysizes plugin](https://github.com/aFarkas/lazysizes/tree/gh-pages/plugins/object-fit).

You might also define your images with a `background-image` (directly set in a `style` attribute, so it can be managed from the view...) and use the more supported `background-size` property. Some lazyload plugins (see http://jquery.eisbehr.de/lazy/example_load-background-images for instance) offer this approach with a `data-src` attribute.

In both case the `cover` value seems, as you suggested, the right value to use with `object-fit` or `background-size`.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `max-width: 100%` and `max-height: 200px` for your images to preserve aspect ratio but take not more than `200px` or `height`. Demo:

```css
.person {
  border: 10px solid transparent;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  opacity: 0.7;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.person:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container text-center list">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <p><strong>Counter-Strike</strong></p>
      <br />
      <a href="">
        <img class="person" src="http://i.imgur.com/Zckhfao.jpg" />
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <p><strong>Rainbow 6: Siege</strong></p>
      <br />
      <img class="img-circle person" src="http://i.imgur.com/Dho2UVH.png" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <p><strong>FIFA</strong></p>
      <br />
      <img class="person" src="http://i.imgur.com/Dho2UVH.png" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <p><strong>League of Legends</strong></p>
      <br />
      <img class="person" src="http://i.imgur.com/Dho2UVH.png" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <p><strong>Racing</strong></p>
      <br />
      <img class="person" src="http://i.imgur.com/Dho2UVH.png" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <p><strong>Battlefield</strong></p>
      <br />
      <img class="person" src="http://i.imgur.com/bFg40Dj.jpg" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: it looks bad anyway. They are all different sizes.

Comment: @Tiago They will have different sizes if you want to preserve aspect ratio. You won't be able to achieve the same size and preserve aspect ratio.

Comment: @Tiago Can you please clarify your desired result?

Comment: I just want all the images to be the same size. I can do that by using a fixed height and width but the images will get blurry

Comment: @Tiago I know, but what do you want?

Comment: i mean in your example the images are still all different sizes.

Comment: @Tiago I understand this. It's not clear how do you want images to have the same sizes and preserve aspect ratio **at the same time**. Can you please be clear on **what you want**?